# Xcode 360 panorama video

Tags: xcode, video, pan, 360-degrees

Anyone met with the development application to view panoramic video 360?
Do you have any ideas for this or tutorials?

I find this http://www.ptgrey.com/products/ladybugSDK/

But I don't know how to work with it

or there is another option - to realize this in html 5
http://krpano.com/docu/html5/ # fact

but with this, I also did not work

Do you have any experience in this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out www.gopano.com
And their player(for non commercial use): https://github.com/EyeSee360/Pantaloons

Amey